# Stop jQuery hover effect when element is not hovered anymore

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hover

My script:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $(".inner").hover( function (e) {
        $(this).find(".info").stop().fadeIn(410);
    }, function() {
        $(this).find(".info").stop().fadeOut(410);
    });
});
```

When I mouseover the div .inner it will play the animation but when I quickly mouse out and mous in again it will stop on the place where I mouse out it, to make it easier.

http://www.sakesalverda.nl/projects/ and hover on a website image and quickly mouse out and hover the image of the website again and you will see it will not fully make the animation

Answer (score 1):

There surely is a jQuery solution, but I would use CSS for this, it's much easier and im most cases the performance is better:

```
.inner .info {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .42s;
    transition: opacity .4s;
}
.inner:hover .info {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Works on all [major browsers](http://caniuse.com/css-opacity), but [IE8 would need a fallback](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-opacity/). One downside is, that IE8 and IE9 won't have the fading effect, but in my opinion, thats a death we can afford to die, as those browsers are at only 5% these days. And the showing / hiding will work, just not as nicely as with modern browsers.

Comment: I have already tried this, the reason that I use jQuery is that with a css transition the text will fade in ugly: it goes from semi-bold in 0s to bold or something like that, with jQuery I don't have that problem

Comment: Is there a reason you are using jQuery 1.4.4? It seems to be all right with 1.11: http://jsfiddle.net/59SDK/

Comment: thanks problem is solved now. I used it because I don't know which jQuery I have to include, can you explain me how I know which jQuery I have to include

Comment: Just to add: `$(this).find(".info").stop().fadeTo(410, 1);` and `$(this).find(".info").stop().fadeTo(410, 0);` works OK even with your version of jQuery.

Comment: As Eadel pointed out, it will work with your jQuery Version when you set the complete variables: [jquery.com/fadein/](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/). I still would always try to use the newest jQuery Version, which is 1.11.1 now. (Or 2.1.1 if you don't need to support IE8)